# Get a callback when a WKInterfaceSlider lost WKCrownSequencer focus

Tags: ios, slider, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible with watchkit 3.2 to get a callbak when a WKInterfaceSlider (or any WKInterfaceObject) lost WKCrownSequencer focus (e.g. no more value change by digital crown)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do so. Only WKInterfacePicker has such methods that is inside WKInterfaceController.

Comment: That's what I figured.